# PrintPreviewControl HitTest() and interaction

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to implement a HitTest() function for PrintPreviewControl?

I want to know which page the user clicked on, and the offset from TopLeft. (see image below)

The end-goal is to provide full interactivity with the PrintPreviewControl, whereby users can click and drag objects. I understand that this control does not hold my objects. I have my own list of objects. I know where they were rendered on the page. I simply want to get mouse locations within pages that I can use to select my own objects, and then refresh the print preview control when I drag and drop.

[image]

Comment: IIRC, that Control has `Columns` and `Row` properties, plus the `StartPage`. You should be able to determine in which page a MouseDown is generated using the `e.Location` value and the grid determined by Columns/Rows in the Preview.

Comment: That looks like PrintPreviewDialog, not PrintPreviewControl.  It matters, makes getting to the [private variables](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Printing/PrintPreviewControl.cs,49) you need twice as hard.  Not really practical.

Comment: Right. If that's actually a PrintPreviewDialog (or did you *steal* the ToolStrip? :), it has a public `PrintPreviewControl` property that returns the Control used for the Preview. You can get Rows and Columns from it (and subscribe to its `MouseDown` event).

Comment: You are correct, this is the PrintPreviewDialog, but you can get the PrintPreviewControl from it. And, you can get Rows and Columns, but creating a reliable HitTest from just those and the MouseClick location is sketchy. I'm considering using my own PrintController like the PreviewPrintController as a means of getting each page rectangle. Hoping someone might have worked this out already.

Comment: You need to print the Preview yourself and keep track of the Rectangle where the content of a page is drawn, so you can, e.g., change its border to a different color, *highlight* it (paint over with a semi-transparent color) etc. You can draw directly on a `PrintPreviewControl` using its Paint event. -- Or calculate the bounding rectangle using Columns and Rows. Not complicated, the gap withing the sections is fixed (using the default layouts).